# C code for deleting mailq messages

Tags: c, linux, shell

Currently I am using shell script to delete mailq messages. I want sum help to convert that shell script to C code. Any example or help is appreciated. I just want some basic direction to do it.

This the current code I am using:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
 WORKFILE="/tmp/check.mq"
 MAILLIST="emailadress"

mailq|grep -B1 -i temporarily |grep -iv deferred |egrep -i  'jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec' |awk -F" " '{print $1}' |awk '{print   substr($0,10,14)}' |tee -a $WORKFILE |awk '{print "*" $1}' |tee -a mail.mq
mailq|grep -B1 -i unknown|egrep -i 'jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec' |awk -F" " '{print $1}' |awk '{print substr($0,10,14)}' |tee -a $WORKFILE |awk '{print "*" $1}' |tee -a mail.mq
mailq|grep -B1 -i lookup |grep -iv deferred |egrep -i 'jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec' |awk -F" " '{print $1}' |awk '{print substr($0,10,14)}' |tee -a $WORKFILE |awk '{print "*" $1}' |tee -a mail.mq

 cat mail.mq | while read file; do rm -rf /var/spool/mqueue/$file;done
 rm -rf mail.mq
```

Basically I am using substring of last 5 numbers of the message id and sending it to my mailid and than deleting those ids.

Comment: Why do you want to convert this to C, and what have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks Mat
problem is with setuid i want this in C since i want to to give users root priviledges and since C compiles into binary.
Currently i tried calling this script from c program

Comment: That's probably the worst reason to convert something to C. Keep your script, with restricted permissions, and use `sudo`.

Comment: its working if i am calling that script from C and setting setuid in compiled binary usin chown.
But i need whole thing in C.

Comment: Well the go ahead and start coding. Ask questions here when you're stuck on a specific problem.

Comment: Thanks Mat
But the problem is i need to know how to start and how to call mailq in C.
Just initiall help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "system" function to run a shell command, including a pipeline.  It will use the default system shell, which may or may not be ksh on your system, but maybe that won't matter.  If it does matter you can always explicitly say "ksh -c" at the beginning of the command string.

```
system("mailq|grep -B1 -i temporarily |grep -iv deferred |egrep -i  'jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec' |awk -F" " '{print $1}' |awk '{print   substr($0,10,14)}' |tee -a $WORKFILE |awk '{print "*" $1}' |tee -a mail.mq")
```

You will need to figure out how to weave $WORKFILE in there--this should be trivial using snprintf() to construct the command string first.  You can use getenv() to look up the value.